# SharePoint 2010 with InfoPath - Adding a Person field to the Approval Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I've got a list with an approval workflow. I'd like to add a person (people picker) type field to the approval form where a manager can assign the request at the same time of approval.

My field in the list is named "Assigned To" and it is a person type field. Can I add this field to the InfoPath approval form so the approver can populate it from there? If so how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint Designer to add the person type field to the approval workflow.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to get the "Assigned To" field into the Infopath approval template and map it to the List's "Assigned To".